# C help while trying to make a log base ten to work

Tags: c

Hi can u explain why log in the following code gives 10 when giving inputs x=10
and y=10?It actually gives whatever the value is the x and y.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double x, y, z, a, s, w;
int main()
{
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    z = x + y;

    if (x > y)
    {
        printf("x\n");
    }

    if (y > x)
    {
        printf("y\n");
    }

    if (x == y)
    {
        printf("equals\n");

    }

    a = pow(x, y);
    printf("%lf\n", a);

    s = log10(x);
    w = log10(y);
    printf("%f\t%f", x, y);

    return (0);
}
```

Well it's true I did change last printf to s and w however I get the result=2.302585

Comment: `printf("%f\t%f",x,y);` prints `x` and `y`, which are `10` (the inputs). Were you expecting something else?

Comment: Aside: `printf("%lf\n",a);` is for `long double` (unlike `scanf` which signifies `double`), change to `printf("%f\n",a);`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Since when?  C11 says, under `fprintf()`, that the length modifier `l` _Specifies that …; or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier._  This is for consistency with `scanf()` et al.  The length modifier `L` _Specifies that a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to a long double argument._  This too is consistent with `scanf()`.  Note that C90 did not specify a behaviour for `%lf` with `printf()`, but C99 and C11 do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of printing `s` and `w` you printed `x` and `y` so I see no reason why the program will not print whatever the value `x` and `y` have.

Answer (score 0):

At the last printf statement you are printing "x" and "y", that value never changed on the program after the user input their values. If you want to print other relevant information like "s" or "w" you should add another printf statement or modify the last one.